# Google Cloud SQL Timeseries Statistics

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-app-engine-php

I have a massive table that records events happening on our website. It has tens of millions of rows.

I've already tried adding indexing and other optimizations.

However, it's still very taxing on our server (even though we have quite a powerful one) and takes 20 seconds on some large graph/chart queries. So long in fact that our daemon intervenes to kill the queries often.

Currently we have a Google Compute instance on the frontend and a Google SQL instance on the backend.

**So my question is this - is there some better way of storing an querying time series data using the Google Cloud?**

I mean, do they have some specialist server or storage engine?

I need something I can connect to my php application.

Comment: Take a look at Cloud Bigtable: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series

Comment: ah I see, I'm a bit confused on how to query it if I can't use mysql - where does it say how to connect to it from a php application? :)

Comment: It supports the HBase API, but it doesn't look like there's a native PHP Client. Moving from mysql to a store like Bigtable can involve a non-trivial investment. If you are really maxing out your mysql instance, you can consider sharding the data across multiple instances (storing a subset of data on each instance), but that also requires a non-trivial investment and has its own tradeoffs. There are a lot of articles on mysql sharding on the web.

Comment: That's a pity, I was hoping they would have some solution for me. Kind of got me excited for a short time. I'm not opposed to a non-trivial investment. It's a business we're running. Just wish there was a way. Seems crazy that they have this powerful thing that doesn't connect to 99% of websites.

Comment: You can run the HBase REST server (http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_rest) to interact with Cloud Bigtable via a REST API, which should work from any language but it won't perform as well as the native API since it has to go through an extra hop (not to say it will be slow, but it will be slower relative to a native client). Cloud Bigtable is very powerful, but it's also much "lower level" than a relational database. You will need to do some analysis to decide if it's a good fit for your use case.

Comment: I've been doing some digging. They have a system called cloud datastore that has a bigtable in the backend. It has a JSON API......https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/

Comment: Yes, that's another option to evaluate, but keep this article (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention) in mind if you plan to write a lot of data. You may have to design your schema in such a way that there isn't a lot of advantage of using Datastore over Bigtable. By the way, are you querying this data for analytics or another purpose? If the large queries are only meant for analytics, you can also consider exporting the data to BigQuery (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) for analysis.

Comment: @Vadim its for live statistics system. So many design constraints to deal with...

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch is awesome for time series data.

You can run it on compute engine, or they have a hosted version.

It is accessed via an HTTP JSON API, and there are several PHP clients (although I tend to make the API calls directly as i find it better to understand their query language that way).

https://www.elastic.co

They also have an automated graphing interface for time series data. It's called Kibana.

Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

Update: I missed the important part of the question "**using the Google Cloud?**"  My answer does not use any specialized GC services or infrastructure.

---

I have used ElasticSearch for storing events and profiling information from a web site.  I even wrote a statsd backend storing stat information in elasticsearch.

After elasticsearch changed kibana from 3 to 4, I found the interface extremely bad for looking at stats.  You can only chart 1 metric from each query, so if you want to chart time, average time, and avg time of 90% you must do 3 queries, instead of 1 that returns 3 values.  (the same issue existing in 3, just version 4 looked more ugly and was more confusing to my users)

My recommendation is to choose a Time Series Database that is supported by graphana - a time series charting front end.  OpenTSDB stores information in a hadoop-like format, so it will be able to scale out massively.  Most of the others store events similar to row-based information.

For capturing statistics, you can either use statsd or reimann (or reimann and then statsd).  Reimann can add alerting and monitoring before events are sent to your stats database, statsd merely collates, averages, and flushes stats to a DB.

- http://docs.grafana.org/
- https://github.com/markkimsal/statsd-elasticsearch-backend
- https://github.com/etsy/statsd
- http://riemann.io/